# Facing problem in starting MariaDB server. Getting error: "Too many arguments (first extra is '”–wsrep-new-cluster”')"

Tags: mariadb, galera

I had created a 2-node Maria DB Galera Cluster in the RHEL server, which was running properly.

Then for some reason, one of the nodes(let's call it "Node2") stopped working, so I tried to remove that node from my first node by removing the IP of that server from the "server.cnf" property file.

Then my first node(let's call it "Node1") stopped working so I tried to disable all cluster configurations at Node1 by disabling the wsrep* properties.
After that, I started getting the error **"Too many arguments (first extra is '”–wsrep-new-cluster”**

**I have tried this command "mysqld_safe --wsrep-recover" as well, but the issue was not fixed.**

So to fix it, I uninstalled Maria DB from both of the nodes and then reinstalled it.

Now after reinstallation, Node2 has started working properly, but at Node1 I am still getting the same error **"Too many arguments (first extra is '”–wsrep-new-cluster”"** although I have not modified anything there.

The detailed log output is as follows:

```
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 11.0.3-MariaDB source revision 70905bcb9059dcc40db3b73bc46a36c7d40f1e10 as process 14566
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Resetting space id's in the doublewrite buffer
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=512 bytes)
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: End of log at LSN=2640760968
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Opened 3 undo tablespaces
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments in 3 undo tablespaces are active.
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 2640760968; transaction id 355136
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] Plugin 'wsrep-provider' is disabled.
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230927 16:45:34
/usr/sbin/mariadbd: Too many arguments (first extra is '”–wsrep-new-cluster”').
2023-09-27 16:45:34 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have used isn't a normal hyphen:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select hex('–'), hex('-');
+------------+----------+
| hex('–')   | hex('-') |
+------------+----------+
| E28093     | 2D       |
+------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Also use [--wsrep-new-cluster](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadbd-options/#-wsrep-new-cluster) (two hyphens(`-`)).

Comment: I am getting the error "Too many arguments (first extra is '”–wsrep-new-cluster”"" in my logs, but I have not configured the parameter "'”–wsrep-new-cluster” anywhere.

Comment: Here was mistakenly starting the server using "systemctl start mariadb" while it was the first node of the cluster. The problem got resolved by using the command "galera-new-cluster" to start the first server.